# CombineLatest, but only push for the left

Tags: system.reactive

I need to implement a version of `CombineLatest` (I'll call it `WithLatest` here) that calls the selector for every item on the left and the latest item on the right. It shouldn't push for items on the right changing only.

I think whether this is built `Observable.Create` or a combination of existing extensions is not particularly important; I'll be making this a "boxed" extension method either way.

**Example**

```
var left = new Subject<int>();
var right = new Subject<int>();

left.WithLatest(right, (l,r) => l + " " + r).Dump();

left.OnNext(1);   // <1>
left.OnNext(2);   // <2>
right.OnNext(1);  // <3>
right.OnNext(2);  // <4>
left.OnNext(3);   // <5>
```

should yield

```
2 1
3 2
```

**Edit**: The logic of my example goes:

1. Left becomes populated with 1. Right is empty, no values pushed.
2. Left becomes updated with 2 (it forgets the previous value). Right is still empty, so nothing is pushed.
3. Right becomes populated with 1, so Left = 2 (the latest value), Right = 1 is pushed. *Up to this point, there is no difference between `WithLatest` and `CombineLatest`*
4. Right is updated -- nothing is pushed. *This is what's different*
5. Left is updated with 3, so Left = 3, Right = 2 (the latest value) is pushed.

---

It's been suggested that I try:

```
var lr = right.ObserveOn(Scheduler.TaskPool).Latest();
left.Select(l => l + " " + lr.First()).Dump();
```

but this blocks on the current thread for my test.

Comment: You want to do this w/ existing combinators only, or is an implementation using `Create()` an option?

Comment: Your example doesn't match what I'd expect from your description.  The first item returned in your example seems to be triggered by a change on the right observable. Should `WithLatest` trigger on the first right if there are already items from left?

Comment: See "CombineVeryLatest" in [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211134/how-to-throttle-event-stream-using-rx/3224723#3224723) - very similar pattern.

Comment: @Gideon Engelberth: Agree. That left me puzzled too. According to the description, the algorithm should yield "3 2" only.

Comment: Can you writs your answer up as an answer rather than an edit to the question?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using existing operators.

```
Func<int, int, string> selector = (l, r) => l + " " + r;

var query = right.Publish(rs => left.Zip(rs.MostRecent(0), selector).SkipUntil(rs));
```

- `Publish` ensures we only ever subscribe to `right` once and share the subscription among all subscribers to `rs`.
- `MostRecent` turns an `IObservable<T>` into an `IEnumerable<T>` that always yields the most recently emitted value from the source observable.
- `Zip` between `IObservable<T>` and `IEnumerable<U>` emits a value each time the observable emits a value.
- `SkipUntil` skips the pairs `(l, r)` which occur before `right` ever emits a value.

Answer (score 4):

I also had the same need for a `CombineLatest` which "pushes only for the left".

I made the solution an "overload" of `Observable.Sample`, because that's what the method does:
It samples a `source` (right) with a `sampler` (left), with the additional capability of providing a `resultSelector` (like in CombineLatest).

```cs
public static IObservable<TResult> Sample<TSource, TSample, TResult>(
    this IObservable<TSource> source,
    IObservable<TSample> sampler,
    Func<TSource, TSample, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    var multiSampler = sampler.Publish().RefCount();
    return source.CombineLatest(multiSampler, resultSelector).Sample(multiSampler);
}
```

Comment: Usage for the example above:  
`right.Sample(left, (r,l) => l + " " + r).Dump();` It produces "3 2" which is IMO correct

Answer (score 1):

Based on the solution picked by the post author I think there's an even simpler solution utilizing [DistinctUntilChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229494(v=vs.103).aspx):

```
public static IObservable<TResult> CombineLatestOnLeft<TLeft, TRight, TResult>(this IObservable<TLeft> leftSource, IObservable<TRight> rightSource, Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult> selector) {
        return leftSource
            .Select<TLeft, Tuple<TLeft, int>>(Tuple.Create<TLeft, int>)
            .CombineLatest(rightSource,
                (l, r) => new { Index = l.Item2, Left = l.Item1, Right = r })
            .DistinctUntilChanged(x => x.Index)
            .Select(x => selector(x.Left, x.Right));
    }
```

or even

```
public static IObservable<TResult> CombineLatestOnLeft<TLeft, TRight, TResult>(this IObservable<TLeft> leftSource, IObservable<TRight> rightSource, Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult> selector) {
        return leftSource
            .CombineLatest(rightSource,
                (l, r) => new { Left = l, Right = r })
            .DistinctUntilChanged(x => x.Left)
            .Select(x => selector(x.Left, x.Right));
    }
```

if you only care about distinct values of `leftSource`

Answer (score 1):

I made a RX operator for project today that does this.

Here's my solutions:

```
    public static IObservable<Tuple<TSource, TTarget>> JoinLeftSoft<TSource, TTarget>(
        this IObservable<TSource> source, IObservable<TTarget> right)
    {
        return source
            .Select(x => new Tuple<object, TSource>(new object(), x))
            .CombineLatest(right, (l, r) => new Tuple<object, TSource, TTarget>(l.Item1, l.Item2, r))
            .DistinctUntilChanged(t => t.Item1)
            .Select(t => new Tuple<TSource, TTarget>(t.Item2, t.Item3));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

On latest *System.Reactive*, we can use `WithLatestFrom` extension method.

```
left.WithLatestFrom(right, (l, r) => l + " " + r).Dump();
```

The result would be below correctly.

```
3 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the hacky way using Create - didn't actually build it, mea culpa if it doesn't actually work :)

```
public static IObservable<TRet> WithLatest<TLeft, TRight, TRet>(
        this IObservable<TLeft> lhs, 
        IObservable<TRight> rhs, 
        Func<TLeft, TRight, TRet> sel)
{
    return Observable.Create<TRet>(subj => {
        bool rhsSet = false;
        bool deaded = false;
        var latestRhs = default(TRight);

        Action onDeaded = null;

        var rhsDisp = rhs.Subscribe(
            x => { latestRhs = x; rhsSet = true; }, 
            ex => { subj.OnError(ex); onDeaded(); });

        var lhsDisp = lhs
            .Where(_ => deaded == false && rhsSet == true)
            .Subscribe(
                x => subj.OnNext(sel(x, latestRhs)),
                ex => { subj.OnError(ex); onDeaded(); },
                () => { subj.OnCompleted(); onDeaded(); });

        onDeaded = () => {
            deaded = true;
            if (lhsDisp != null) {
                lhsDisp.Dispose();
                lhsDisp = null;
            }
            if (rhsDisp != null) {
                rhsDisp.Dispose();
                rhsDisp = null;
            }
        };

        return onDeaded;
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm getting "1 0", "2 0" for my example.

Comment: Whoops, my where clause was bad, try it now

Comment: _Now it's just "3 2"_  - 
which is the correct solution according to the requirement: _only push for the left_