# .net reactive extensions - block an event for a time after each occurrence

Tags: c#, .net, reactive-programming

I have an event that normally should not come more than 1/second.
But it may happen from time to time that is comes 2 o 3 times in one second.

So I want to do something like this with reactive extensions:
If an event comes -> process it.
If any other come in the next x seconds ignore them.
Than if after the x seconds comes a another event -> process it
and so on.

Id do not want to use the Throttle function since I want to respond as fast as possible if the events come in normal timing.

Is there any built in function in the Rx that does this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999503/rx-how-can-i-respond-immediately-and-throttle-subsequent-requests