# Learning Rx: How to use .Scan on the output of .Window for an observable sequence of bool values

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a sequence of true false values like so

```
        var alternatingTrueFalse = Observable.Generate(
            true,
            _ => true,
            x => !x,
            x => x,
            _ => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(new Random().Next(2000)))
            .Take(20).Publish();
        alternatingTrueFalse.Connect();
        var buffered = alternatingTrueFalse
            .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
            .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"{TimeStamp} {string.Join(",", x)}"));
```

I want to look at the sequence in terms of 500 ms (max) windows / buffers. If there is only one true value (and nothing else) inside one such window, I want to flip a switch (just call a command, print to console for now). Then, when the next false value arrives, I want to flip the switch back and close the current window / buffer of the original sequence and start a new one.

### Using Buffer + Scan to flip the switch

So far I've come up with a way to do this on a Buffer, with this. However, the buffers are open too long, they are always 500 ms.

```
        var buffered = alternatingTrueFalse
            .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
        var output = buffered
            .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"{TimeStamp} {string.Join(",", x)}"));

        var isFlipped = buffered.Scan(false, 
                (x, y) => 
                { 
                    if (y.Count == 0)
                    {
                        return x;
                    }
                    return y.Count == 1 && y.First();
                });

        isFlipped.DumpTimes("Flipped");
```

I'm trying to figure out how to use Window instead of Buffer to be able to flip the switch back on the first false after an isolated true. But I can't seem to get it right, I'm not quite fluent in Rx yet and not sure how to use the windowOpening / Closing values for it.

## Example output

original

```
2017-10-07 20:21:39.302 True,False   // Rapid values should not flip the switch (actually they should flip a different switch)
2017-10-07 20:21:39.797 True         // Flip the switch here
2017-10-07 20:21:40.302 False        // Flip the switch back and close the current window
2017-10-07 20:21:40.797 True         // Flip the switch here
2017-10-07 20:21:41.297 
2017-10-07 20:21:41.798 False        // Etc...
...
2017-10-07 20:21:43.297 True
2017-10-07 20:21:43.800 False,True   // Example of a window that is open too long, because it is not closed immediately upon the false value
...
```

buffer + scan

```
2017-10-07 20:47:15.154 True
2017-10-07 20:47:15.163 - Flipped-->True
2017-10-07 20:47:15.659 False,True   // Example of a window open too long
2017-10-07 20:47:15.661 - Flipped-->False
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution not using the `Scan` approach.

The issue seems to be closing the buffer based on two conditions - maximum time or specific value. This one is based on [an old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35557411/buffer-until-quiet-behavior-from-reactive/35560532#35560532)

```
public static IObservable<IList<TSource>> BufferWithClosingValue<TSource>(
    this IObservable<TSource> source, 
    TimeSpan maxTime, 
    TSource closingValue)
{
    return source.GroupByUntil(_ => true,
                               g => g.Where(i => i.Equals(closingValue)).Select(_ => Unit.Default)
                                     .Merge(Observable.Timer(maxTime).Select(_ => Unit.Default)))
                 .SelectMany(i => i.ToList());
}
```

Example usage would be

```
alternatingTrueFalse.BufferWithClosingValue( TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), false );
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to give me a pretty good building block to continue with. I'd still like to learn more about window and scan, but groupbyuntill also seems good.

Comment: Just FYI I used this in a bit more interesting scenario here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46492665/how-to-use-reactive-ui-to-trigger-a-different-action-following-a-button-click-vs

Comment: Okay, but the issue remains the same - close buffer/window based on multiple conditions. I'm not sure what you can accomplish with `Scan` because you can't control the buffer/window closing. Maybe you can apply it directly on source observable and build from there

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to create custom operator not based on other operator as it will take much more CPU and memory.

Here is the clean version of the same method.

```
public static IObservable<IEnumerable<TValue>> BufferWithThrottle<TValue>(this IObservable<TValue> @this, int maxAmount, TimeSpan threshold)
{
    var buffer = new List<TValue>();

    return Observable.Create<IEnumerable<TValue>>(observer =>
    {
        var aTimer = new Timer();
        void Clear()
        {
            aTimer.Stop();
            buffer.Clear();
        }
        void OnNext()
        {
            observer.OnNext(buffer);
            Clear();
        }
        aTimer.Interval = threshold.TotalMilliseconds;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
        aTimer.Elapsed += (sender, args) => OnNext();
        var subscription = @this.Subscribe(value =>
        {
            buffer.Add(value);
            if (buffer.Count >= maxAmount)
                OnNext();
            else
            {
                aTimer.Stop();
                aTimer.Start();
            }
        });
        return Disposable.Create(() =>
        {
            Clear();
            subscription.Dispose();
        });
    });
}
```