# Kinect "sleep" command

Tags: c#, kinect

I'm trying to write a C# hand and fingertip detection program, for now I have been able to get the hand points and store them in a List but I'm a little stuck regarding how to present that data in order to visualise the results.

My solution at the moment is to draw a black point in a canvas (I'm trying to use Ellipse shape for this) for each point I have, but I think that this is so time consuming that I can't see the results.

Is there a way to make the Kinect ignore the next, for exemple, 30 frames, or in other words can I make kinect only call the onFrameReadyEvent once every 30 Frames?

If anyone has any other solution for result presentation feel free to share ;)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `OnFrameReadyEvent` is an event, look into [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx).

Rx has a `Throttle` extension method that you can use to only get 1 frame a second. For an example, check out this SO question:
[How to throttle event stream using RX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211134/how-to-throttle-event-stream-using-rx)

Comment: Although I believe Rx is a great solution to this, I believe something like `source.Buffer(1, 30).Concat()` would work perfectly, as opposed to `Throttle`, which would not work, because frame events occur constantly and therefore the throttle window would never end. Another solution might be `Sample`, which might be what you meant. `Sample` would work *perfectly*, assuming you wanted a time-based solution.

Comment: That is true.  I guess I took "once every 30 Frames" as "Only one per second".  To get literally one frame out of every 30 you can also `Skip` 29 frames and get the same results.  Rx is awesome like that :)

Comment: Indeed. You'd need to `Skip(29).Repeat()`, though. ;) Oh, Rx... how did we do this stuff before Rx, again? I forget. :)

Comment: Still trying to catch up on Rx ( first time I hear about it so thanks =D ).

The "once every 30 Frames" was only an example the main point here is that I want to "slow" the kinect calls to the OnFrameReadyEvent so that I have time to process the Frame Data.

Comment: Rx changed the way that I used the Kinect (and for the most part, how I look at events).  One thing I never really thought about before I started using Rx was when to clean up my event subscriptions.  Since Observable subscriptions return `IDisposable` objects, it makes event lifecycle management really easy.  Good luck and enjoy Rx!

Comment: Thanks a lot guys Rx really seems like the breakthrought I was looking for since it allows me to do so much more than just a "sleep" command. I'm still geting the hang of this (the channel 9 videos on this are just genius) if anyone has a more hands on approach of this please let me know.