# Make combineLatest 'forget' its last Invocation in RxJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm using combineLatest to combine two streams A and B.

If stream A produces a value it combines it with the last value of B and produces a value on the result stream.

However i want it to forget about the last value of B after every invocation, so that the next time an A is chosen a new B needs to be produced for the result stream to produce a new value.

I want this to be symmetric so the same goes for the other way around.

Example:

```
A -- 1 -- 2 -- 3 ------------- 4 ------

               (3,1)         (4,3)

B -------------- 1 ---- 2 --- 3 --------
```

I found this answer: 
[How to throttle event stream using RX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211134/how-to-throttle-event-stream-using-rx/3224723#3224723)

However it is written in C# while i need the answer for RxJS.

Comment: So you're not looking for `zip`?

Comment: @Bergi nah, if you look at the example zip would produce: 
(1,1)(2,2)(3,3) completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone struggling as I did:

I just found the [flatMapLatest](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/flatmaplatest.md) function which does exactly what i need.